# AngularJS - simple tutorial wont work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I started out with Angular and came across this code that should work, but it doesn't.

Angular is downloaded and added via the script tag and it is correct, others tutorials worked before.

I have tried everything but just doesnt seem to find out what's the problem. Started learning from the book AngularJS from O'Reilly.

```
<html ng-app="nameApp">
<head>
<title>Angular Training</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="NameCtrl">

<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="name in names"> {{ name }}
        <a href="" ng-click="removeName(name)">remove</a>
    </li>

</ul>
<form ng-submit="addName()">

    <input type="text" ng-model="enteredName">
    <input type="submit" value="add">

</form>
<script src='unzipped___AngularJS-1.3.12\angular-1.3.12\angular.min.js'></script>
<script>

    var nameApp = angular.module('nameApp', []);

    nameApp.controller('NameCtrl', function ($scope){


                $scope.names = ['Larry','Curly', 'Moe'];

                $scope.addName = function(){

                    $scope.names.push($scope.enteredName);
                    $scope.enteredName = '';

                };

                $scope.removeName = function(name){

                    var i = $scope.names.indexOf(name);

                    $scope.names.splice(i, 1);
                };

    });     
</script>



</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/eqk5adc1/3/

Comment: Select AngularJS from Frameworks & Extensions dropdown in jsfiddle and it will work

Comment: Works fine:: https://jsfiddle.net/eqk5adc1/5/

Comment: Always check console in cases like this - you can see that "angular is not defined" because you didnt included it.

Comment: When the question form says that you must include code in the question, **you must include code in the question**.

Comment: And yes, unsurprisingly jsfiddle can't find the library at "unzipped___AngularJS-1.3.12\angular-1.3.12\angular.min.js".

Comment: @user3050538 The code seems to be working properly.  I simply replaced your source for script tag with:

 //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js

https://jsfiddle.net/5qv2e2jm/

Comment: of course it didnt find the angular on my machine, silly me !  :D

Answer (score 2):

https://jsfiddle.net/5qv2e2jm/
Try adding this

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: yes this works ( just replaced the source for angular). But on my machine, when I download Angular on it and get the source on my machine it doesnt work, and thats the reason I posted on here because, like you guys pointed out, the code is OK.

Comment: just try to ensure that your directory is pointing in the right place, before doing a relative path like you have, start with a full path (C:\...\angular.min.js) and work your way down.

Comment: @user3050538 When you say "on my machine" are you running a server on your machine or just opening the HTML file from your hard drive?

Comment: no Server, but this is a Javascript framework so in my opinion a server could be omitted, Sometimes other code works well, sometimes not, so the path is correct

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments, it sounds like you are likely running into security issues.  Modern browsers can typically prevent loading external js files from the local file system for security reasons.  This is dependent on the browser you use.  For more information, this security concept is called the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

"this is a Javascript frameworks so in my opinion a server could be omitted..."

This is not necessarily true because of the aforementioned security concept.  If you are using Firefox you can disable this security feature (though I would recommend only temporarily) using the following steps:

1. Navigate to [about:config](http://about:config)
2. In the search bar type `security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy`
3. Set this property to false.

These steps should allow local js files to be loaded in Firefox.  In the end, it may be easier to simply setup a server or use a cheap cloud server (google, amazon, c9.io, etc.).  Another option might be just using jsfiddle like you did above.